# Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed nested stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Why am I getting this error for a SP calling another SP.  If I call the SP directory it works just fine.

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure TEST1, Line 25
>   Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

**SP1 -> SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [TEST].[TEST1]
    @EventId INT = NULL,
    @MemberId INT = NULL,
    @Type INT = NULL,
    @Scheduled BIT = 0,
    @DivisionId INT = NULL,
    @DivisionTeamId INT = NULL,
    @Date DATETIME = NULL,
    @GymCourtId INT = NULL
AS
```

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

```
CREATE TABLE #GridGames (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NULL,
    [Round] [int] NULL,
    [GameType] [int] NULL,
.
.
.
.
INSERT INTO #GridGames 
EXEC [TEST].[TEST] @EventId, @MemberId, @Type, @Scheduled, @DivisionId, @DivisionTeamId, @Date, @GymCourtId
```

**SP**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [TEST].[TEST]
    @EventId INT = NULL,
    @MemberId INT = NULL,
    @Type INT = NULL,
    @Scheduled BIT = 0,
    @DivisionId INT = NULL,
    @DivisionTeamId INT = NULL,
    @Date DATETIME = NULL,
    @GymCourtId INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DayAhead DATETIME;

    IF(@Date IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @DayAhead = DATEADD (DAY , 1 , @Date);
    END

SELECT
        game.Id,
        game.[Type] AS GameType,
        game.[Date],
```

**UPDATE**

Line 25 is pointing to `game.[Date]` in the nested stored proc, but that is a datetime null type, and my temp table also has that, what gives?

Comment: Maybe your definition of `#GridGames` doesn't match the result set produced by `TEST.TEST`? And the error is being reported on line 25 of `TEST1`, not `TEST`, so the `@DayAhead` code in `TEST` is irrelevant.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right. Check definition of #GridGames and match that with the datatype of the result produced by TEST.TEST

Comment: That definition was generated from that SP which generated a table with that type so it can't be and also I dont see other datatimes that could be this issue in regards to an int because those columns are all datetimes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found out why, it's because my parameter order on the inner SP select statement didnt match the temp table order.